# why last echo shown instead of page redirect?

Tags: php

i just check users with AJAX to see if this user already register or not, but after ajax checking when user submit registration from last echo shown instead of redirect what should i do? see thee code to understand what i said:

here is my ajax in Register form

```
    ('#phone').keyup(function(){  
            //run the character number check  
                //get the phone  



        //use ajax to run the check  
          $.ajax({

                url: 'check.php',
                 type: 'POST',
                 dataType: 'html',
                    data: { 
                            phone : $('#phone').val()

                            },
                success:function(response){
                    if(response == "1"){
                        document.getElementById('phone').setCustomValidity("این شماره تلفن قبلا به ثبت رسیده است");
                        }
                        else{
                            document.getElementById('phone').setCustomValidity("");
                        }
                                         }

                    });

 });  


<form id=contactform action="registeropr.php" method="post">
```

//////
here is my server side code

```
if(!is_null($_POST['phone'])){


$phone = trim(strtolower($_POST['phone']));

$phone = mysql_escape_string($phone);

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT phone from users WHERE phone = '$phone' LIMIT 0, 3");
        //$user_data = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $no_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

        if($no_rows > 0){
            echo 1;
                        }
        else{
            echo 2;
            }
                            }
        ///////////////////////////////////////////
        /*else
        {
            $email = trim(strtolower($_POST['email']));
            $email = mysql_escape_string($email);

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT Email from users WHERE Email = '$email' LIMIT 0, 3");

         $no_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

        if($no_rows > 0){
            echo 3;
                        }
        else{
            echo 4;
            }
```

here it is i echo the number to see what happend to show the right message to user, but if user set all field correctly if he submit form the last echo shown instead od redirecting

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP- Ajax and Redirect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4033483/php-ajax-and-redirect)

Comment: I do not see any redirect in the code shown.

Comment: for example if user input a phone number that exsist in database it echo 1 so in ajax i catch it and show the proper message to user so user eenter new phopne after that when form submited instad of redirect to balbalhbla.php it shows the last echo:

Answer (score 0):

**APPROACH:1**

In your AJAX code , compare it like this

```
 success:function(response){
                    if(response == 1){
                                  ^ ^ quotes removed.
```

**APPROACH:2**

Your code should be something like this. [*There was an EXTRA brace* (**removed**) and you need to *replace your echo statement with a redirect header* as shown below].

```
 <?php
    $phone = trim(strtolower($_POST['phone']));

    $phone = mysql_escape_string($phone);

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT phone from users WHERE phone = '$phone' LIMIT 0, 3");
    //$user_data = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $no_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

    if($no_rows > 0){
        echo 1;
    }
    else{
        header("location:yourpage.php");

    }
```